# Integral $\int {1\over x^2+8x-3}\quad dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I am looking for a solution/explanation as to how to solve the following integral (sorry I am not familiar with the math language used here);

$$\int {1\over x^2+8x-3}\quad dx$$

I solved this problem a couple times and got the solution;

$$\frac{-19}{\sqrt{19}}\text{ln}\left|\frac{x+4+\sqrt{19}}{x^2+8x-3}\right|$$

I am fairly confident in this solution, however, symbolab and wolframalpha disagree. I am not sure if this is simply an alternate form of the solution or if it is incorrect altogether. I began solving the problem by completing the square and making the substitution $x+4=\sqrt{19}\sec(\theta)$ and $dx=\sqrt{19}\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)$. From here I was able to pull out the constant $\frac{\sqrt{19}}{19}$, cancel out a $\tan(\theta)$ and was left with he constant times the integral of $\frac{\sec(\theta)}{\tan(\theta)}$. This simplifies to $\csc(\theta)$. I integrated this with the "multiply by $1/1$" method and used the substitution $u=\csc(\theta)+\cot(\theta)$ and $-du=\csc^2(\theta)+\csc(\theta)\cot(\theta)$. After solving, replacing my substitution, and using the trig identity, $x+4=\sqrt{19}\sec(\theta)$, I got my answer.
If anyone could help me determine if this answer is a correct form or how to solve it correctly it would be much appreciated. Again, sorry for the math formatting.

Comment: I edited part of your question, doing a quick search would show you how to do mathjax, you already have 21 points which means you have been here for a while, the least you can do is to learn the math language used here instead of being sorry for not being familiar with the math language used here, it should not take you more than 5 minutes to fix your post.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, don't you get a $\sqrt{13}$, not $\sqrt{19}$?

Comment: @ChrisCuster No, you do $(x+4)^2-19=x^2+8x-3$. I think you're thinking of the constant term as $+3$.

Comment: My mistake.   You're right.

Comment: @Arjang Actually, I have not been here long, I have only ever posted one question before. I will be getting on learning that though. Having only ever posed one question I hadn't taken the time to learn it. Thanks though.

Comment: @DoctorDave : all you need to learn will take you 3 minutes, follow this 3 steps 
1.click edit on your post
2.View the mathjax of your own question
3.play around with the texts in within the $ signs, observe the change in the view pane below the test you modify.
by now you are 70% of the way to being an expert in mathjax.

Comment: @Arjang Got it, I'll make sure to become familiar with it before posting any more questions.

Comment: @DoctorDave : also when you are viewing the equations, you can right click on the math part, in menu select "Show Math as"->""TeX Commands" and you can see what was used to make the math. At least that is what works for me on windows and chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would complete the square as you suggested.   Get $\int\dfrac1{(x+4)^2-19}\operatorname dx=\dfrac1{19}\int(\dfrac 1{(\dfrac{x+4}{\sqrt{19}})^2-1}\operatorname dx$.  Then we use that $\int\dfrac 1{1-x^2}\operatorname dx=\dfrac12\ln\dfrac{\mid1+x\mid}{\mid1-x\mid}+C$, to get $\dfrac1{2\sqrt{19}}\ln\dfrac{\mid\sqrt{19}-(x+4)\mid}{\mid\sqrt{19}+(x+4)\mid}+C$.

Answer (score 4):

This quadratic has two real roots, $x = -4\pm\sqrt{19}$, so this is better handled with partial fractions:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + 8x -3} = \int\left[\frac{1}{x+4-\sqrt{19}}-\frac{1}{x+4+\sqrt{19}}\right]\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{19}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{19}}\ln\left|\frac{x+4-\sqrt{19}}{x+4+\sqrt{19}}\right|
$$

Comment: I had not considered this method. I am working through the rest of my calculus book on my own and have not learned this yet. I'll look into it and give it a try, it certainly looks easier.

Answer (score 4):

Eyeballfrog is correct, as you can see. However, I'd like to tell you something:

**Whenever you are not sure about the antiderivative, just take the derivative in respect to the variable and see if it is the same as the integrand. If so, then it's correct; otherwise, it is not.**